# Uncaught Error: Graph container element not found

Tags: javascript, morris.js

I saw answer "JavaScript's code gets executed before the DOM contains #annual element. Put the javascript after the div or use jQuery.ready()" But I don't know to put after what div?

`<script src="/bower_components/morris.js/morris.min.js"></script>` this is script include?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TxWTE.png)

error:

```
Uncaught Error: Graph container element not found
    at d [as constructor] (morris.min.js:6)
    at d.c [as constructor] (morris.min.js:6)
    at new d (morris.min.js:6)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (dashboard.js:129)
    at j (jquery.min.js:2)
    at k (jquery.min.js:2)
```

Comment: Include inside head tag

Comment: That means either put your js code to generate the graph under `$(document).ready()` or put the code on the last

Comment: I put the script tag(morris.js) at the end of the file

Comment: Inside head tag is still "Graph container element not found"

Answer (score 1):

If you are using adminLte template in an angular project, you have to delete the import dashboard.js from the scripts array in angular.json file.

Answer (score 1):

i confirm resolution :
im using AdminLTE in angular :

delete the import dashboard.js from the scripts array in angular.json file.